# How to update value of useState in call back

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a function named LoginUser , that gets initiated on login button click. When user gets authenticated setUser sould get udpated with the email id of user, but it is not updating it and giving the previous value which is "Logged in User" in console.log. I tried useEffect but it said React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("Logged in User");

const LoginUser = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/login", {
        userID_Login: userIdLogin,
        password_Login: passwordLogin
    }).then((res) => {
        if (!res.data.recordsets) {
            setUser(res.data.message);
            alert("Either you are not authorised or UserId/Password not correct. Plesae contact administrator.")
        } else {
            setUser(res.data.recordset[0].Email);
            console.log(user);
            navigate("/Home");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` method is asynchronous. This is the reason why `console.log` will give you the previous value of the state. In other words: `setState` will schedule a state change, not do it instantly.

You have to place the `useEffect` outside of the callback and listen for changes of `user`.

```js
...
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(user)
  // Do what you want with user
}, [user])

const LoginUser = () => {
...
```

Comment: Hi Lars, Thank you for your reply. I have used useEffect outside of the callback but it is not reacting for changes of user inside call back function and that's returning the same previous value as it is.

Comment: @Akky Are you sure you set the data correctly? Can you provide a full example?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async function.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("Logged in User");
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('user', user)
  // your logic here
}, [user])
```

Comment: Hi lazy.lizard, should I use my LoginUser function inside useEffect where you have mentioned "// your logic here". I think then my button click will not be able to trigger the LoginUser function.

Comment: No, LoginUser is a function that fires only when you provide login and password and in general it's a login form submit handler. `useEffect` in your case is almost needless since you can handle response result in `.then()` callback. I only ment that you can execute arbitrary code when value of `user` state changes.